# Crawling error Bing and Google

Tags: sitemap, bing, google-crawlers

I'm encountering some error while publishing my website. 
I've submit my sitemap.xml to Bing and Google using both webmaster tools and both seems have some troubles to crawl my website.

Google doesn't display error message but only 58 pages have been crawled since there is more thant 500 pages submitted by my sitemap.
Furthermore, Bing displays and error while loading my sitemap throught https but is always pending on http.

Could anyone help me to investigate where is my error please ?

Here is my sitemap url :

https://www.unaboria.fr/sitemap.xml
http://www.unaboria.fr/sitemap.xml

My robots.txt is here and allows every robots : http(s)://www.unaboria.fr/robots.txt

Thank you in advance,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

About the Bing Pending status, this will solve it.

After 14 days of pending status, I found this link, to PING Bing with your sitemap. It's a kind of wake-up call for my sitemap. A few hours later, my site was indexed.

1. Upload your sitemap (but you already did hence the pending status)
2. Type in your browser:

   ```
   http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap={full url to your sitemap}
   ```

You receive a response with something like this:

> Thanks for submitting your Sitemap. Join the Bing Webmaster Tools to see your Sitemaps status and more reports on how you are doing on Bing.